# Capture HTML canvas as GIF/JPG/PNG/PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, export, png

Is it possible to capture or print what's displayed in an HTML canvas as an image or PDF?

I'd like to generate an image via canvas and be able to generate a PNG from that image.

Comment: Here's a pythonic solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395649/python-pil-create-and-save-image-from-data-uri
in addition to answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3514404/529442

Comment: [HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#Examples)

Comment: Example here http://www.freakyjolly.com/convert-html-document-into-image-jpg-png-from-canvas/

Comment: You might find canvas2image library useful for this: https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image

Comment: If someone is looking for an answer related to React, I wrote two tutorials about it yesterday: [React Component to Image](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-image) and [React Component to PDF](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-pdf).

Comment: This is a related post on if and how to capture the entire contents of the canvas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77916769/how-to-capture-the-full-contents-of-a-canvas when the contents may be larger than the canvas or when the contents may extend past the boundaries of the canvas.

Answer (score 846, accepted):

Original answer was specific to a similar question. This has been revised:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas')
const img    = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
```

With the value in `img` you can write it out as a new image like so:

```
document.getElementById('existing-image-id').src = img
```

or

```
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: Thanks michael, looks like getContext together with toDataURL would do it

Comment: one more question, how can I save the image I got in this tag to server. Any guess??

Comment: @Surya - In the example above, I would use AJAX to POST the img variable to the server. Alternatively, you could set the value of a hidden field in a form.

Comment: Is this technique suitable for making a screenshot of a web page?

Comment: @jnthnclrk I don't think so, since it's only saving canvas (until all your page is a canvas)

Comment: @jnthnclrk you can take a look for screenshot making at screengrab addon for firefox sources (and seems for chrome too?) - http://code.google.com/p/screengrab/source/browse/trunk/src/chrome/content/NsUtils.js maybe it will help

Comment: But if i use var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); am getting the background as complete black. How to rectify that

Comment: @Gauti Likely a browser issue. JPEG isn't supported by all (should work on Chrome/Firefox though)

Comment: @Gauti It's likely your background is the RGBA colour (0,0,0,0) i.e. completely transparent black. JPEG does not support transparency and so this is converted to just be black I think.

Comment: @donohoe This is not working on IOS7 when the canvas contains an SVG image.

Comment: Oh come on. I answered this in 2009. What do you expect?

Comment: Instead of using `document.write()` you can use:  `document.getElementById('theID_of_a_DIV_to_Wrap_IMG_In').innerHTML = "<img src='" + img + "'>";`

Comment: Works for me right now, but somehow not a year ago or so. I knew about this before, but it didn't work before.

Comment: doesn't work for me - for `png` I get transparent box image (no visible data), for `jpeg` the same as reported above - all black. Any ideas?

Comment: @donohoe actually you answered it in August 2010 :)

Comment: This works **except** on Mac Safari when there is an embedded <image> tag. Safari ignores the image, whether the image is base64 or a link. Has anyone got in to this issue and resolved it? Would really like to know.

Comment: I would only add this: be careful when you scale your image. If you let user manipulate scaled image (i.e. you only show small tile when dropping on google map) you probably want to keep original (usually much bigger) image in hidden img and use this as source you feed to canvas. Othervise you will get qyality of your image reduced since drawing img on canvas will take whatever size of your img.

Comment: what about saving image from svg (not canvas)?

Comment: It would use a lot less memory to do something like `var img = new Image(); img.src = canvas.toDataURL(); document.body.appendChild(img);`. The `document.write` code is making the data URL, them making a HTML string, then putting a copy of that string in the DOM, the browser then has to parse that HTML string, put another copy on the image element, then parse it again to turn the data URL into image data, then finally it can show the image. For a screen size image that's a huge amount of memory/copying/parsing. Just a suggestion

Comment: @DilaGurung you need to do `var img = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");` . See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667458/todataurl-not-a-function

Comment: if "/home/Desktop/dataset/"  is my path and i want to save image as " image_1.jpg" , what changes i need to do  --> ('<img src="'+img+'"/>');   ??  @donohoe

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi just make a canvas, draw that SVG over the canvas aaand... use this to grab the image just drawn.

Answer (score 122):

HTML5 provides Canvas.toDataURL(mimetype) which is implemented in Opera, Firefox, and Safari 4 beta. There are a number of security restrictions, however (mostly to do with drawing content from another origin onto the canvas).

So you don't need an additional library.

e.g.

```
 <canvas id=canvas width=200 height=200></canvas>
 <script>
      window.onload = function() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          context.fillStyle = "green";
          context.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
          // no argument defaults to image/png; image/jpeg, etc also work on some
          // implementations -- image/png is the only one that must be supported per spec.
          window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      }
 </script>
```

Theoretically this should create and then navigate to an image with a green square in the middle of it, but I haven't tested.

Comment: Where the image will be saved. Location in my local?

Comment: the image will be displayed as an image in your browser. You can then save it to disk or whatever. Here's a quick and dirty generic "Canvas2PNG" bookmarklet that converts the first canvas in the page to PNG and displays it in the browser in a new window: `javascript:void(window.open().location = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL("image/png"))`

Comment: If the image is a few MB in size, prepare to crash your browser (I did that a while back in FireFox).

Comment: How could this be modified to render multiple images?

Comment: Data URIs have max length, so there is upper limit on the size of an image that you can put to a data url.

Answer (score 49):

I thought I'd extend the scope of this question a bit, with some useful tidbits on the matter.

In order to get the canvas as an image, you should do the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

You can use this to write the image to the page:

```
document.write('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
```

Where "image/png" is a mime type (png is the only one that must be supported). If you would like an array of the supported types you can do something along the lines of this:

```
var imageMimes = ['image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/tiff']; //Extend as necessary 
var acceptedMimes = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < imageMimes.length; i++) {
    if(canvas.toDataURL(imageMimes[i]).search(imageMimes[i])>=0) {
        acceptedMimes[acceptedMimes.length] = imageMimes[i];
    }
}
```

You only need to run this once per page - it should never change through a page's lifecycle.

If you wish to make the user download the file as it is saved you can do the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); //Convert image to 'octet-stream' (Just a download, really)
window.location.href = image;
```

If you're using that with different mime types, be sure to change both instances of image/png, but not the image/octet-stream.
It is also worth mentioning that if you use any cross-domain resources in rendering your canvas, you will encounter a security error when you try to use the toDataUrl method.

Comment: With your solution for downloading the file, I must choose the software I want to use, it's a bit unconvenient... Is there a way to re-replace the mime as png once downloaded?

Comment: @So4ne I don't think so, it has to be an image/octet-stream to prompt the user for a download. If you get rid of that line, you'll end up with the page redirecting to the image. I would love to know if someone else knows a way to do this nicely, though.

Comment: using target="_blank" on <a> link and .click() it should work, too to trigger the download (tested with FF data-urls and download="filename" for text/csv and text/plain)

Comment: This is great. Thanks! But what if I want to save to server and not local? Will a form file input accept the img src as something that is uploadable?

Comment: Oops. Just found the answer. Leaving the previous question in case someone else is looking as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server

Comment: How can this be used to download multiple images?

Comment: is it possible to export canvas as video in format like mp4?

Answer (score 46):

```
function exportCanvasAsPNG(id, fileName) {

    var canvasElement = document.getElementById(id);

    var MIME_TYPE = "image/png";

    var imgURL = canvasElement.toDataURL(MIME_TYPE);

    var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
    dlLink.download = fileName;
    dlLink.href = imgURL;
    dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = [MIME_TYPE, dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

    document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
    dlLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(dlLink);
}
```

Comment: The saved file stays in .svg format. How to save it as png?

Comment: This is a nice solution except that it may not work on IE. Getting error "The data area passed to a system call is too small"

Comment: In Chrome it says "Network error", while in Firefox it works great. (On Linux)

Answer (score 19):

I would use "[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)". It just work great. It uses webkit engine (used in Chrome, Safari, etc.), and it is very easy to use:

```
wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/ this_question.pdf
```

That's it!

[Try it](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Comment: I'm in the wkhtmltopdf camp, too.  We've been using it for archiving and its AMAZING.

Comment: How to use WKHTMLtoPDF in page that required login info ?
I am using Jsreport to convert to PDF but I capture my content with HTML2Canvas ,I have issue with sending the Canvas as parameter to JSreport

Comment: @khaledDehia check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287386/generate-pdf-behind-authentication-wall

Answer (score 15):

Here is some help if you do the download through a server (this way you can name/convert/post-process/etc your file):

-Post data using `toDataURL`

-Set the headers

```
$filename = "test.jpg"; //or png
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
if($msie = !strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false)      
  header("Content-type: application/force-download");else       
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");   
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Expires: 0"); header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: public");
```

-create image

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(substr($data,strpos($data,',')+1)));
```

-export image [as JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570015/669677)

```
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($output,  255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
imagecopy($output, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($output);
exit();
```

-or [as transparent PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813540/669677)

```
imagesavealpha($img, true);
imagepng($img);
die($img);
```

Answer (score 13):

This is the other way, without strings although I don't really know if it's faster or not. Instead of toDataURL (as all questions here propose). In my case want to prevent dataUrl/base64 since I need a Array buffer or view. So the other method in HTMLCanvasElement is `toBlob`. (TypeScript function):

```
    export function canvasToArrayBuffer(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, mime: string): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => canvas.toBlob(async (d) => {
    if (d) {
      const r = new FileReader();
      r.addEventListener('loadend', e => {
        const ab = r.result;
        if (ab) {
          resolve(ab as ArrayBuffer);
        }
        else {
           reject(new Error('Expected FileReader result'));
        }
      }); r.addEventListener('error', e => {
        reject(e)
      });
      r.readAsArrayBuffer(d);
    }
    else {
      reject(new Error('Expected toBlob() to be defined'));
    }
  }, mime));
}
```

Another advantage of blobs is you can create ObjectUrls to represent data as files, similar to HTMLInputFile's 'files' member. More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: This answer must be marked as the correct one and need to be upvoted. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Another interesting solution is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).
It's a headless WebKit scriptable with JavaScript or CoffeeScript.

One of the use case is screen capture : you can programmatically capture web contents, including SVG and Canvas and/or Create web site screenshots with thumbnail preview.

The best entry point is  the [screen capture](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) wiki page.

Here is a good example for polar clock (from RaphaelJS):

```
>phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png
```

Do you want to render a page to a PDF ?

```
> phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jakarta&printable=yes' jakarta.pdf
```

Comment: +1: PhantomJS is simple, well documented and well thought-out system, perfect for this job. It allows much more than just grabbing a canvas too - for instance, you can modify the page or part of it (through JS) before grabbing so make it look just the way you want it. Perfect!

Comment: PhantomJs is now obsolete

Comment: PhantomJS is not "obsolete" - it is unmaintained.... It still supports most ES6 stuff, and is still the only modern/decent headless browser that works on x86 and does not need compiling. Therefore it still the only [proper] headless browser that works on various embedded or lightweight distros/systems.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery, which quite a lot of people do, then you would implement the accepted answer like so:

```
var canvas = $("#mycanvas")[0];
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

$("#elememt-to-write-to").html('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: Do note that the *only* usage of jQuery here is the selection of the canvas. `.toDataURL` is native JS.

Comment: I have save issue some one can help me see this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131763/how-to-save-the-canvas-text-image-in-gallery?noredirect=1#comment39171750_25131763

Comment: Pure (100%) jQuery solution is the following:
`$('<img>').attr('src',$('#mycanvas')[0].toDataURL('image/png')).appendTo($('#element-to-write-to').empty());`
Exactly one line.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is

> [canvas.toDataURL(type, quality)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

---

And I want to provide an example for someone like me who wants to save SVG to PNG(also can add some text if you wish), which may be from an Online source or font-awesome icon, etc.

### Example

100% javascript and no other 3-rd library.

```html
<script>
  (() => {
    window.onload = () => {
      // Test 1: SVG from Online
      const canvas = new Canvas(650, 500)
      // canvas.DrawGrid() // If you want to show grid, you can use it.
      const svg2img = new SVG2IMG(canvas.canvas, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg")
      svg2img.AddText("Hello", 100, 250, {mode: "fill", color: "yellow", alpha: 0.8})
      svg2img.AddText("world", 200, 250, {mode: "stroke", color: "red"})
      svg2img.AddText("!", 280, 250, {color: "#f700ff", size: "72px"})
      svg2img.Build("Test.png")

      // Test 2: URI.data
      const canvas2 = new Canvas(180, 180)
      const uriData = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
      const svg2img2 = new SVG2IMG(canvas2.canvas, uriData)
      svg2img2.Build("SmileWink.png")

      // Test 3: Exists SVG
      ImportFontAwesome()
      const range = document.createRange()
      const fragSmile = range.createContextualFragment(`<i class="far fa-smile" style="background-color:black;color:yellow"></i>`)
      document.querySelector(`body`).append(fragSmile)

      // use MutationObserver wait the fontawesome convert ``<i class="far fa-smile"></i>`` to SVG. If you write the element in the HTML, then you can skip this hassle way.
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationRecordList, observer) => {
        for (const mutation of mutationRecordList) {
          switch (mutation.type) {
            case "childList":
              const targetSVG = mutation.target.querySelector(`svg`)
              if (targetSVG !== null) {
                const canvas3 = new Canvas(64, 64) //  Focus here. The part of the observer is not important.
                const svg2img3 = new SVG2IMG(canvas3.canvas, SVG2IMG.Convert2URIData(targetSVG))
                svg2img3.Build("Smile.png")
                targetSVG.remove() // This SVG is created by font-awesome, and it's an extra element. I don't want to see it.
                observer.disconnect()
                return
              }
          }
        }
      })
      observer.observe(document.querySelector(`body`), {childList: true})
    }
  })()

  class SVG2IMG {
    /**
     * @param {HTMLCanvasElement} canvas
     * @param {string} src "http://.../xxx.svg"  or "data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64}"
     * */
    constructor(canvas, src) {
      this.canvas = canvas;
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
      this.src = src
      this.addTextList = []
    }

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} node
     * @param {string} mediaType: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Common_examples_%5B10%5D
     * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes
     * */
    static Convert2URIData(node, mediaType = 'data:image/svg+xml') {
      const base64 = btoa(node.outerHTML)
      return `${mediaType};base64,${base64}`
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} text
     * @param {int} x
     * @param {int} y
     * @param {"stroke"|"fill"} mode
     * @param {string} size, "30px"
     * @param {string} font, example: "Arial"
     * @param {string} color, example: "#3ae016" or "yellow"
     * @param {int} alpha, 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#transparency
     * */
    AddText(text, x, y, {mode = "fill", size = "32px", font = "Arial", color = "black", alpha = 1.0}) {
      const drawFunc = (text, x, y, mode, font) => {
        return () => {
          // https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp
          // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText
          const context = this.context
          const originAlpha = context.globalAlpha
          context.globalAlpha = alpha
          context.font = `${size} ${font}`

          switch (mode) {
            case "fill":
              context.fillStyle = color
              context.fillText(text, x, y)
              break
            case "stroke":
              context.strokeStyle = color
              context.strokeText(text, x, y)
              break
            default:
              throw Error(`Unknown mode:${mode}`)
          }
          context.globalAlpha = originAlpha
        }
      }
      this.addTextList.push(drawFunc(text, x, y, mode, font))
    }

    /**
     * @description When the build is finished, you can click the filename to download the PNG or mouse enters to copy PNG to the clipboard.
     * */
    Build(filename = "download.png") {
      const img = new Image()
      img.src = this.src
      img.crossOrigin = "anonymous" // Fixes: Tainted canvases may not be exported

      img.onload = (event) => {
        this.context.drawImage(event.target, 0, 0)
        for (const drawTextFunc of this.addTextList) {
          drawTextFunc()
        }

        // create a "a" node for download
        const a = document.createElement('a')
        document.querySelector('body').append(a)
        a.innerText = filename
        a.download = filename

        const quality = 1.0
        // a.target = "_blank"
        a.href = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png", quality)
        a.append(this.canvas)
      }

      this.canvas.onmouseenter = (event) => {
        // set background to white. Otherwise, background-color is black.
        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over" // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation // https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_globalcompositeoperation.asp
        this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)"
        this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
        this.canvas.toBlob(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({'image/png': blob})])) // copy to clipboard
      }
    }
  }

  class Canvas {

    /**
     * @description for do something like that: ``<canvas width="" height=""></>canvas>``
     **/
    constructor(w, h) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
      document.querySelector(`body`).append(canvas)
      this.canvas = canvas;
      [this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height] = [w, h]
    }

    /**
     * @description If your SVG is large, you may want to know which part is what you wanted.
     * */
    DrawGrid(step = 100) {
      const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
      const w = this.canvas.width
      const h = this.canvas.height

      // Draw the vertical line.
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (let x = 0; x <= w; x += step) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, h);
      }
      // set the color of the line
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)'
      ctx.lineWidth = 1
      ctx.stroke();

      // Draw the horizontal line.
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (let y = 0; y <= h; y += step) {
        ctx.moveTo(0, y)
        ctx.lineTo(w, y)
      }
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)'
      ctx.lineWidth = 5
      ctx.stroke()
    }
  }

  function ImportFontAwesome() {
    const range = document.createRange()
    const frag = range.createContextualFragment(`
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-UwcC/iaz5ziHX7V6LjSKaXgCuRRqbTp1QHpbOJ4l1nw2/boCfZ2KlFIqBUA/uRVF0onbREnY9do8rM/uT/ilqw==" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
`)
    document.querySelector("head").append(frag)
  }
</script>
```

if you want to run on stackoverflow and move your mouse on the picture may get error

> DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document

You can copy the code on your local machine and run it again, will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`upload image` from `<canvas />`:

```js
async function canvasToBlob(canvas) {
  if (canvas.toBlob) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      canvas.toBlob(resolve)
    })
  } else {
    throw new Error('canvas.toBlob Invalid')
  }
}

await canvasToBlob(yourCanvasEl)
```

Answer (score 0):

On some versions of Chrome, you can:

1. Use the draw image function `ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, w, h);`
2. Right-click on the canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can use jspdf to capture a canvas into an image or pdf like this:

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');              
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
```

More info: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is just to take the blob of it and set the img src to a new object URL of that blob, then add that image to a PDF using some library, like

```js
var ok = document.createElement("canvas")
ok.width = 400
ok.height = 140
var ctx = ok.getContext("2d");
for(let k = 0; k < ok.height; k++) 
  (
    k 
    % 
    Math.floor(
      (
        Math.random()
      ) *
      10
    )
    == 
    0
  ) && (y => {
    for(var i = 0; i < ok.width; i++) {
      if(i % 25 == 0) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = Math.random()
        ctx.fillStyle = (
          "rgb(" + 
          Math.random() * 255 + "," +
          Math.random() * 255 + "," +
          Math.random() * 255 + ")"
        );

        (wdth =>
          ctx.fillRect(
            Math.sin(
              i * Math.PI / 180
            ) * 
              Math.random() *
              ok.width,
            Math.cos(
              i * Math.PI / 180,
            ) * wdth + y,
            wdth,
            wdth
          )
        )(15)
      }
    }
  })(k)

ok.toBlob(blob => {
  k.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
})
```

```html
<img id=k>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to work with low-level byte data, you can get the raw bytes of the canvas, then, depending on the file spec, write the raw image data into the necessary bytes of the data. you just need to call `ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.widht, ctx.canvas.height)` to get the raw image data, then based on the file specification, write it to that

Answer (score 0):

if you want to emebed the canvas you can use this snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id=canvas width=200 height=200></canvas>
    <iframe id='img' width=200 height=200></iframe>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.fillStyle = "green";
            context.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            document.getElementById('img').src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Capture to a Gif](https://www.crx4chrome.com/extensions/eapecadlmfblmnfnojebefkbginhggeh/) ([unpacked](https://github.com/milahu/capture-to-a-gif-by-nonegame)) is a chrome extension to record an HTML canvas to a GIF file

postprocessing: you will need to cut and compress the video (ffmpeg, kdenlive, ...)

why compress? the result will have a constant framerate, not the original framerate. this is a limitation of all canvas-recording-tools ([ccapture](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/), [jsgif](https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif), [gif-capture-canvas](https://github.com/abagames/gif-capture-canvas), ...)